# Expose a file as static resource

Tags: spring, application.properties, staticresource

I'm trying to expose a file as a static resource via application properties

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  resources:
    static-locations: classpath:/openapi/
```

With this configuration I am able to access the File that exists within the openapi folder
But, I want to expose only the file.
So I tried this:

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  resources:
    static-locations: classpath:/openapi/RequisitionService.openapi3.json
```

But with this configuration I am not able to access the file. 
Any idea how we can expose a specific file as a static resource?

Answer (score 0):

Use below properties for files:

```xml
spring:
  profiles: default
  resources:
    static-locations: file:/openapi/RequisitionService.openapi3.json
```

check this ref for more information on this - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Comment: Hi. I tried this, but still cannot access the file from here: http://localhost:8081/RequisitionService.openapi3.json. The file is stored here: src\main\resources\openapi. do I need to mention classpath somewhere?